# Is there a more elegant way for multiple attributes of a UIImage?

Tags: swift

Is there a way to create like an array of attributes which I want a UIImage to have? Because I often have to do this repetitive pattern (I would like to get rid of the 'userImage.layer' part if possible):

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    
    userImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    userImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    userImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    // Initialization code
}
```

Comment: You can create an extension for `UIImageView` and just add it to the imageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No officially supported way of grouping those attributes in UIKit*.

Many people end up building a thin "styling layer" on top of UIKit. Some approaches I've seen, from more popular to less popular:

- Create some kind mapping of "styles" to attributes, and manually apply the style to the UIImage at some point in the view/view controller lifecycle (awakeFromNib is a good spot).
- Subclass the class you want to style and create some kind of custom initializer that takes in a "style". You'd only end up with 1 subclass. Not every UIKit class can be safely subclassed, so YMMV.
- Subclass the classes you want to style and have each subclass map to different styles. You'd end up with many subclasses. Not every UIKit class can be safely subclassed, so YMMV.

* There's UIAppearance, but not every attribute or class supports it. You can usually look at the header files to figure that out.

Comment: Okay, that's a shame since Apple is so focused on simple and elegant design, but thanks for your extensive answer! I will try writing a subclass I think.

Comment: @yoKurt note that awakeFromNib wont be called if you add your view programatically

Comment: What would be a more secure way? In the CollectionView delegate function which creates the cells?